# where is "View Selected" in blender 2.83?

Tags: 3d-view

where is "View Selected" in blender 2.83?

(i used to bind this to "Numpad ." with emulate numpad on using 2.7 style keys)

now i am disabled, i can't just centre the view on objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the default keymap is still <kbd>Numpad Period</kbd> key.

Or use the menu View>Frame Selected. If you enabled tooltips in the preferences it will show you what is the current keyboard shortcut on gray letters on the right of the command.

If you need to change the shortcut, right click on the command and select Change Shortcut.

[image]